# Jmeter cookie manager does not seem to work with HTTPS login

Tags: cookies, authentication, jmeter

I am trying to analyse a site using Jmeter. My plan includes a HTTPS login, for which I have included a HTTP Cookie manager in the ThreadGroup.
But still all subsequent requests are being forwarded to the login page. Seeing in the Tree View Listener, I can see that there is no cookie in any request or response.

Has anyone made Jmeter cookie manager work with HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten it work on several different websites.  I assume you've verified via Tree View that the login was successful?

It could be that login is generating a unique key that was hardcoded during recording and should be removed.

Where do you have your cookie manager placed, and which option did you choose?  The manager should be at the highest level.

Comment: It looks likes its not jmeter problem. I am able to login via jmeter to one of our parallel sites.